# how to get selected items from grid by using check box in angular and type script in a button click

Tags: angular, typescript

I have grid in angular *ngfor and it has a checbox, and by using that i want to get checked item from grid in a button click `startW`

```
 <table
                                                            class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-left">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th></th>
                                                                    <th>Region</th>
                                                                    <th>Sub Region</th>
                                                                    <th>Site ID</th>
                                                                    <th>Site Type</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr *ngFor="let hub of asyncNewLinkHubModel | async  | paginate: { id: 'activities', itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }">
                                                                    <td>
                                                                   
                                                                        <input type="checkbox"
                                                                        name="chkHub"
                                                                        value="{{hub}}"
                                                                         />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>{{hub.REGION_CODE}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{hub.REGION_SUB_CODE}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{hub.SITE_ID}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{hub.MW_CATEGORY}}</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            </table>
   <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="startW(1)" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    style="width: 100%; border-radius: 8px;">
                                    Start action
                                </button>
```

In typescript .ts file i have below code but without any value

```
 startWf(num:number){
console.log(this.hub);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a local variable in your TS-file where you put the chosen value in and a method that does the job.

***TS***

```
selectedHub: any;

setSelectedHub(hub: any): void {
    this.selectedHub = hub;
}
```

Then you have to react on the change-event of the checkbox and call the method while passing the value

***HTML***

```
<input type="checkbox"
   name="chkHub"
   value="{{hub}}"
   (change)="setSelectedHub(hub)"
/>
```

Now you only have to let your button call the `startW()` method and use the selected value:

***TS***

```
startW(): void {
    /* your code */

    console.log(this.selectedHub);
}
```

***HTML***

```
<button mat-raised-button type="button" 
    (click)="startW()" 
    class="btn btn-primary"
    style="width: 100%; border-radius: 8px;">
    Start action
</button>
```